# Kafka JUnit Test failing due to FileSystemException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to do some testing using the 
[EmbeddedKafkaCluster](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/utils/EmbeddedKafkaCluster.java) from Kafka's integration test utils library. Something similar to the Integration Test examples [Integration Test examples here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.1.2-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaIntegrationTest.java).
But I am hitting `java.nio.file.FileSystemException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\junit3544952207288614104\junit965058698809817752\inputTopic-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.


at org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.KafkaEmbedded.stop(KafkaEmbedded.java:138)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.EmbeddedKafkaCluster.stop(EmbeddedKafkaCluster.java:119)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.EmbeddedKafkaCluster.after(EmbeddedKafkaCluster.java:150)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:50)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\junit3544952207288614104\junit965058698809817752\inputTopic-0\00000000000000000000.timeindex: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.visitFile(Utils.java:757)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.visitFile(Utils.java:746)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:746)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.integration.utils.KafkaEmbedded.stop(KafkaEmbedded.java:136)
... 10 more
```

Deleting the files and re running does not work - it creates a new file every time anyway.

I am only using 1 broker and these are my brokerConfigs:

```
 brokerConfig.setProperty("offsets.topic.num.partitions", "1");      
 brokerConfig.setProperty("transaction.state.log.num.partitions", "1");
```

My code is pretty similar to the [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.1.2-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaIntegrationTest.java) mentioned before. With the exception of using

```
public static final EmbeddedKafkaCluster CLUSTER = new EmbeddedKafkaCluster(1, brokerConfig);
```

in place of

```
public static final EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster CLUSTER = new EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster();
```

Comment: Hi Laura. Kafka does not work very well on Microsoft Windows. May you run your tests on a Linux system?